# How to fix "SVG Not defined" in JEST unit testing

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs, svg.js

I'm trying to setup an unit test case for a function defined in a typescript class.  This class is dependent on svg.js.
Now when I am trying to unit test the function with jest, it throws error
SVG.extend or SVG is not a function.

We have tried ways in jest.config.js file for the testEnvironment to be node to jsdom.

Code for ts is as follows
    import SVG from 'svg.js';

```
export class DrawManager {
  private static _drawingStage : SVG.Nested|undefined;
  private static _canvas : SVG.Doc|undefined;
}

static start(div: string) {
    this._canvas = SVG(div)
    this._drawingStage = this._canvas.nested();
}
```

code for unit testing is as follows

```
import { DrawManager } from './drawmanager';
describe('Test for Draw Manager', () => {
    it('should process task loader method', () => {
    DrawManager.start('drawing');
 });
});
```

We are expecting output pass to test case without any SVG dependency problem and run the test case with the initiated svg class

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. What you need to do is create a setupFile for jest.
setupJestMock.ts for example

With this content:

```
const obj = require('@svgdotjs/svg.js');
const SVG = (arg) => {
  return obj.SVG(arg)
};

Object.assign(SVG, obj);

(global as any).SVG = SVG;
```

then add it to you jest configuration either in package.json or  whatever way  you configure jest:

I have it in my jest.config.json

```
"setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/setupJestMock.ts"
  ],
```